# iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, dyld, dynamic-library

This crash has been a blocking issue I used the following steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create a Cocoa Touch Framework project
- Add a swift file and a class *Dog*
- Build a framework for device
- Create a Single View application in Swift
- Import framework into app project
- Instantiate swift class from the framework in ViewController
- Build and run an app on the device

The app immediate crashed upon launching, here is console log:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkTest03.framework/FrameworkTest03
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/FA6BAAC8-1AAD-49B4-8326-F30F66458CB6/FrameworkTest03App.app/FrameworkTest03App
  Reason: image not found
```

I have tried to build on iOS 7.1 and 8.0 devices, they both have the same crash. However, I can build an app and run on the simulator fine. Also, I am aware that I can change the framework to form *Required* to *Optional* in *Link Binary With Libraries*, but it did not completely resolve the problem, the app crashed when I create an instance of *Dog*. The behavior is different on the device and simulator, I suspect that we can't distribute a framework for the device using a beta version of Xcode. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: What I don't understand is why all other third party frameworks work out of the box and can easily be dragged and dropped into `Link Binary with Libraries` and somehow Xcode knows to copy them into your app bundle, whereas for custom frameworks this simply doesn't happen.

Comment: sazzad hissain khan's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib is the best answer..

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129141/2020034. It works

Comment: you can make a fat library , you can see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977145/3992606

Comment: **Xcode version does not match**, solved with
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55738882/5443510 .

Answer (score 1076, accepted):

In the target's **General** tab, there is an **Embedded Binaries** field. When you add the framework there the crash is resolved.

Reference is [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/991384#991384) on Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: I have the framework in the Embedded Binaries and I have the Copy Phase as well set to "Frameworks". It crashes anyways.

Comment: This only solved on debugging mode. Error will again occur when you archive or build a project

Comment: Adding @executable_path/Frameworks to the 'Runpath Search Path' solved this problem i.e. in addition to adding the framework to 'Embedded Binaries'

Comment: On Xcode 6.1.1 adding it to embedded binaries was enough for me. It works both in debug and when archiving builds.

Comment: I have already added the framework in the Embedded Binaries section but still the app crashes with the message in the console 
"dyld: library not loaded:
reason: image not found" 
appears if the app is allowed to run on the device with iOS 9.1 where as the app smoothly runs on the simulator.

Comment: Same problem occurred, and solution not working in xcode 7.2 just after revoking the certificate.

Comment: Works, but this causes `Found an unexpected Mach-O header` error when try to generate ipa. Any idea?

Comment: You can change the framework to from Required to Optional in your app project. Link Binary With Libraries, but it did not completely resolve the problem, the app crashed when I create an instance of class

Comment: This really helped me. While the subsequent error shown missing @rpath/libSwift* I had to enable 'Embedded Content Contains Swift Code' as well because my new version of embedded framework is now written in  Swift unlike the older version.

Comment: I found over at this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104975/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib-image-not-found) that worked for me. It was by adding to the Runpath Search Paths the string @executable_path/Frameworks. After doing this the error stopped appearing.

Comment: That apple link is broken

Comment: in a real device i tested whole ways and did not get answer, but finally I removed cocoaPod from my project and again reinstall it, the problem solved and my app run in device!! this is the remove cocoaPod answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765245/2201814

Comment: This solution will work. Don't forget a clean and delete of derived data for good luck (that helped me). Good luck!

Comment: You have to set `Embed & Sign` for your SharedCode framework in "Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded Content

Comment: As @luckyhandler wrote, on Xcode 11 and above the lists of "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and "Embedded Binaries" are combined into a single list named "Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded Content". There, you should find your .framework in the list, and change to "Embed & Sign"

Comment: For some reason my framework was on the list after I added it to the project but it was set to "Do not embed" by XCode 11. Changed it to Embed & Sign and it worked.

Answer (score 273):

#### For iOS greater than or equal to 8

Under the target's General tab, in the Embedded Binaries section add the framework. This will copy the framework into the compiled so that it can be linked to at runtime.

[image]

**Why is this happening? :** because the framework you are linking to is compiled as a dynamically linked framework and thus is linked to at runtime.

** Note:** Embedding custom frameworks is only supported in iOS > 8 and thus an alternative solution that works on older versions of iOS follows.

#### For iOS less than 8

If you influence this framework (have access to the source code/build process) you may change this framework to be statically linked rather than dynamically linked. This will cause the code to be included in your compiled app rather than linked to at runtime and thus the framework will not have to be embedded.

** How:** Under the framework's Build Setting tab, in the Linking section, change the *Mach-O Type* to Static Library. You should now not need to include the framework under embedded binaries.

[image: Static Framework]

**Including Assets:** To include things such as images, audio, or xib/nib files I recommend creating a bundle (essentially a directory, more info here bit.ly/ios_bundle) and then load the assets from the bundle using NSBundle.

Comment: This should be "Greater than or Equal To 8".  I've had to do this on iOS 8 as well.

Comment: error `Swift is not supported for static libraries`

Answer (score 146):

Just dragging the framework into your project isn't going to be good enough. That is like being in the same ballpark but not being able to find your kids. Follow these steps:

**1)** Create your framework

- Develop your framework.
- Once your development is complete, `COMMAND`+`B` build your framework and ensure you receive "Build Succeeded".

[image]

**2)** Access your framework

- Once your framework project successfully builds it will then be ready for you to access in your `Products` folder in your project.

[image]

- Right click on your `.framework` and select "Show in Finder".

[image]

**3)** Place framework in your project

- Drag and drop the `.framework` from your Finder window to your app project's "Framework" folder.

[image]

**4)** Configure app project for framework

- Select the top level in your project

[image]

- Choose your target

[image]

- Go to "Build Phases", then "Link Binary with Libraries", and ensure that your framework is included ***with optional selected***.

[image]

- Still in "Build Phases", go to the upper left and select the `+` button. In the drop down choose "New Copy Files Phase".

[image]

- Scroll down to the new "Copy Files" section and ensure that you set `Destination` to "Frameworks". Leave the subpath empty. Then click the `+` button at the bottom left.

[image]

- You will be presented with your project hierarchy. Scroll down to the "Frameworks" folder that you added the framework to in step 3, or search for it in the search bar at the top. Select your framework and click "Add".

[image]

- Ensure that your framework is included with "Code Sign On Copy" selected.

[image]

**5)** Clean, then run your project

- `COMMAND`+`SHIFT`+`K`
- `COMMAND`+`R`

Comment: Good point. It almost works for me. I made a framework A, which inclue Alamofire. My host App(embedded framework A) works in simulators. But when I try to run it in a real iPhone, it crashes with error: Alamofire: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire  
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 xxx/ddcdemo.app/Frameworks/iddc.framework/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: @Brandon Making optional to framework solved my issue. But can you please explain me what is the behaviour of making framework optional ?

Comment: Thank you! In your step 5, I had "Copy only when installing" checked and that was my issue.

Answer (score 53):

Firstly Try to build after Command+Option+Shift+K .If still fails then do below steps.

If anybody is facing this error in Xcode 8 then change your framework status to **Optional** instead of Required under the General Tab of your target.

[image]

Comment: This will make runtime to not recognize classes from the framework

Comment: @azimov is correct. I'm facing this dilemma at the moment. Required causes the "image not found" error and if we try setting it to  optional it will crash at runtime with "unrecognized selector"

Comment: Even though my framework was already in Link Binaries and Embed, I still had to add a Copy Phase.

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
  Referenced from: /Users/{User}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6833A85C-5783-45FA-A4D5-991D286B28C2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B1A0A3B2-92A2-41B0-9884-6DB6995A0D7E/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
(lldb) 

Solution:
Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> + at top to add new Copy Files phase 
Destination = Frameworks
Select the Framework that needs to be copied

Comment: @AdamMendoza I had my app rejected because of doing that.

Comment: @jbouaziz, yes, an error you may run into is due to the .framework being fat, meaning it has architectures that are no supported on iOS such as i386 x86_64 besides the necessary armv7 arm64. The store will give you an error, but you may not see the error in Xcode. Use the loader under Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader. SolutionL make it thin see -> http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

Comment: @AdamMendoza it was a different error, it was saying that I couldn't copy anything to the Framework folder. That's why it was rejected.

Comment: @jbouaziz, you picked my interest. Do you mean the app's Frameworks folder? This is allowed. I just submitted an app and included the AFNetworking.framework and was able to submit to the store. Now, inside the AFNetworking.framework package, which is just a folder, you are not allowed to have non-code files such a .txt files.

Comment: @AdamMendoza I managed to fix it by removing the embedded content contains swfit from my custom framework. What happened was that it was creating a framework folder for the swift libraries which wasn't needed.

Comment: The way I got it to work is clearing the derived data.

Comment: This was the fix necessary for my scenario: deploying an app to an iPad running 9.3.1.  The app contained code that runs on iOS10 only (UNUserNotifications framework).  While I put the correct safeguards in the code so it would BUILD for 9.3.1, was getting this error at runtime.

Answer (score 50):

I created a framework using Swift3/Xcode 8.1 and was consuming it in an Objective-C/Xcode 8.1 project. To fix this issue I had to enable `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` option under `Build Options`.

Have a look at this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This did now work for me at at. The solution to this problem is to go to BuildPhases -> Copy Files -> select Framework under Destination and add your framework. Chances are your libraryis missing here.

Comment: @Harish, The solution you are suggesting is already suggested by several and definitely i take care of that at first point. In my case the framework was added there but still the same issue appeared. Then i dig it by myself. If you have down voted this solution i don't know why you are pretty sure about your way when it didn't work in my case :S

Comment: Awesome this thing works because if using a swift library or a pod to embed in objective C project. Objective C project often has this flag to No.

Answer (score 30):

I had to (on top of what mentioned here) add the following line to **Runpath Search Paths** under *Build Settings* tab:
`@executable_path/Frameworks`

[image]

Comment: It is so strange this is not included by default.  If you unzip and look at your IPA, you should find your frameworks in Payloads/appname.app/Frameworks/.  However, adding this search path has to be there for the app to look in this folder during runtime.  Weird.

Answer (score 28):

I got same kind of issue in iOS 9.x version

```
ISSUE IS: App crashes as soon as I open the app with below error.


dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/######/TestApp.app/TestApp
  Reason: image not found
```

I have resolved this issue by changing `Required` to `Optional` in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` for `UserNotifications.framework` framework.

Comment: I get "warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available." when mark my lib as an optional

Comment: it's worked maybe the reason is some framework didn't run in simulator that's why

Answer (score 26):

You need to add the framework to a new Copy Files Build Phase to ensure that the framework is copied into the application bundle at runtime..

See [How to add a 'Copy Files build phase' to my Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365479/how-to-add-a-copy-files-build-phase-to-my-target) for more information.

Official Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/CreatingaCopyFilesBuildPhase.html

Answer (score 20):

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/<some_path>

It is a runtime error that is caused by `Dynamic Linker`

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/<some_path>
Referenced from: <some_path>
Reason: image not found
```

The error `Library not loaded` with `@rpath` indicates that `Dynamic Linker` cannot find the binary.

1. Check if the dynamic framework was added to the **front** target `General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content (Embedded Binaries)`. It is very simple to drag-and-drop a framework to project with `Copy items if needed`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701037/4770877) and miss to add the framework as implicit dependency in
   `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`(or check in `Add to targets`). In this case during compile time Xcode build it as success but when you run it you get runtime error
2. Check the `@rpath` setup between consumer(application) and producer(dynamic framework):

- Dynamic framework:

  - `Build Settings -> Dynamic Library Install Name(LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME)`. Default is `$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)`
- Application:

  - `Build Settings -> Runpath Search Paths(LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS)`. Default are `@executable_path/Frameworks`, `$(inherited)`
  - `Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks -> Destination, Subpath`

3. Framework's `Mach-O file`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035316/4770877) - Dynamic Library and Application's `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63269154/4770877) - Do Not Embed.

**Dynamic linker**

**`Dynamic Library Install Name(LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME)`** which is used by `loadable bundle`(`Dynamic framework` as a derivative) where `dyld` come into play
`Dynamic Library Install Name` - path to binary file(not .framework). Yes, they have the same name, but `MyFramework.framework` is a `packaged bundle` with `MyFramework` binary file and resources inside.
This path to directory can be absolute or relative(e.g. `@executable_path`, `@loader_path`, `@rpath`). Relative path is more preferable because it is changed together with an anchor that is useful when you distribute your bundle as a single directory

[image]

**absolute path** - **Framework1** example

```
//Framework1 Dynamic Library Install Name
/some_path/Framework1.framework/subfolder1
```

`Relative path` allows  you to define a path in a dynamic way.

**@executable_path**

@executable_path - relative to **executable** binary which loads framework
use case: `Dynamic framework` inside `Application`(application binary path
is @executable_path) or more complex example with `App Extension`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66520509/4770877) which is a part of `Containing App` with `Dynamic Framework` inside. There 2 `@executable_path` for `Application` target (application binary path is @executable_path) and for `App Extension` target(App Extension binary path is @executable_path)) - **Framework2** example

```
//Application bundle(`.app` package) absolute path
/some_path/Application.аpp

//Application binary absolute path 
/some_path/Application.аpp/subfolder1

//Framework2 binary absolute path
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework2.framework/subfolder1

//Framework2 @executable_path == Application binary absolute path <-
/some_path/Application.аpp/subfolder1

//Framework2 Dynamic Library Install Name 
@executable_path/../Frameworks/Framework2.framework/subfolder1

//Framework2 binary resolved absolute path by dyld
/some_path/Application.аpp/subfolder1/../Frameworks/Framework2.framework/subfolder1
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework2.framework/subfolder1
```

**@loader_path**

@loader_path - relative to bundle which causes framework to be loaded. If it is an application than it will be the same as `@executable_path` 
use case: framework with embedded framework - **Framework3_1 with Framework3_2** inside

```
//Framework3_1 binary absolute path
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework3_1.framework/subfolder1

//Framework3_2 binary absolute path
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework3_1.framework/Frameworks/Framework3_2.framework/subfolder1

//Framework3_1 @executable_path == Application binary absolute path <-
/some_path/Application.аpp/subfolder1

//Framework3_1 @loader_path == Framework3_1 @executable_path <-
/some_path/Application.аpp/subfolder1

//Framework3_2 @executable_path == Application binary absolute path <-
/some_path/Application.аpp/subfolder1

//Framework3_2 @loader_path == Framework3_1 binary absolute path <-
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework3_1.framework/subfolder1

//Framework3_2 Dynamic Library Install Name 
@loader_path/../Frameworks/Framework3_2.framework/subfolder1

//Framework3_2 binary resolved absolute path by dyld
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework3_1.framework/subfolder1/../Frameworks/Framework3_2.framework/subfolder1
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework3_1.framework/Frameworks/Framework3_2.framework/subfolder1
```

### @rpath - Runpath Search Path

**Framework2** example

Previously we had to setup a Framework to work with dyld. It is not convenient because the same Framework can not be used with a different configurations. Since this  setup is made on Framework target side it is not possible to configure the same framework for different consumers(applications)

`@rpath` is a compound concept that relies on outer(Application) and nested(Dynamic framework) parts:

- Application:

  - `Runpath Search Paths(LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS)` - `@rpath` - defines a list of templates which will be substituted with `@rpath`. Consumer uses `@rpath` word to point on this list

    ```
     @executable_path/../Frameworks
    ```
  - Review `Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks -> Destination, Subpath` to be sure where exactly the embed framework is located
- Dynamic Framework:

  - `Dynamic Library Install Name(LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME)` - points that `@rpath` is used together with local bundle path to a binary

    ```
    @rpath/Framework2.framework/subfolder1
    ```

```
//Application Runpath Search Paths
@executable_path/../Frameworks

//Framework2 Dynamic Library Install Name
@rpath/Framework2.framework/subfolder1

//Framework2 binary resolved absolute path by dyld
//Framework2 @rpath is replaced by each element of Application Runpath Search Paths
@executable_path/../Frameworks/Framework2.framework/subfolder1
/some_path/Application.аpp/Frameworks/Framework2.framework/subfolder1
```

*`../` - go to the parent of the current directory

`otool` - object file displaying tool

```
//-L print shared libraries used
//Application otool -L
@rpath/Framework2.framework/subfolder1/Framework2

//Framework2 otool -L
@rpath/Framework2.framework/subfolder1/Framework2

//-l print the load commands
//Application otool -l
LC_LOAD_DYLIB
@rpath/Framework2.framework/subfolder1/Framework2

LC_RPATH
@executable_path/../Frameworks

//Framework2 otool -l
LC_ID_DYLIB
@rpath/Framework2.framework/subfolder1/Framework2
```

`install_name_tool` change dynamic shared library install names using `-rpath`

`CocoaPods` uses `use_frameworks!`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257384/4770877) to regulate a `Dynamic Linker`

[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)

[[Java ClassLoader]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66815988/4770877)

Comment: Great explanation! Understand this one and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216858/2082851, then you will understand the behavior of Linked & Embedded frameworks and relating issues.

Answer (score 18):

If you're using **Xcode 11 or newer**:

1. Navigate to the settings of your target and select **General**.

[image: Target Settings/General]

2. Scroll down to **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content**.
3. Make sure the **Embed & Sign** or **Embed Without Signing** value is selected for the **Embed** option if necessary.

[image: Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content section]

Comment: Which one should I choose and what do these two options mean?

Comment: Selecting Embed & Sign adds the framework under Build Phases > Embed Frameworks. It's like a shortcut. But adding it there manually didn't work for me. I had to remove it, and select Embed & Sign in General, and then the issue went away.

Answer (score 13):

Add the framework in Embedded Binaries
[image]

Then Clean and Build.

Answer (score 12):

Surprisingly, not all of the necessary pieces are documented here, at least for Xcode 8.

My case was a custom-built framework as part of the same workspace. It turns out it was being built incorrectly. Based on jeremyhu's last response to this thread:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4687

I had to set `Dynamic Library Install Name Base` (`DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE`) under `Build Settings` of the *Framework* Project and then rebuild it. It was incorrectly set to `$(LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR)` and I had to change it to `@rpath`.

So in the link processing stage in the *App* Project, it was instructing the host App to dynamically load the framework at runtime from `/Library/Frameworks/fw.Framework/fw` (as in, the root of the runtime filesystem) rather than *path-to-App*`/Frameworks/fw.Framework/fw`

Regarding all the other settings: it *does* have to be in 3 places in `Build Phases`, but these are all set at once when you just add it to the `Embedded Binaries` setting of the `General` tab of the hosting App.

I did *not* have to set up an extra `Copy Files` phase, which seems intuitively redundant with respect to the embedding stage anyway.  By checking the tail end of the build transcript we can assure that that's not necessary.

```
PBXCp /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cbcnqafhywqkjufwsvbzckecmjjs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.framework
```

[Many verbose lines removed, but it's clear from the simplified transcript in the Xcode UI.]

I still have *no* idea why Xcode set the `DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE` value incorrectly on me.

Answer (score 11):

Recently ran into this issue with importing CoreNFC on older iphones (e.g. iPhone 6) and Xcode (11.3.1). I was able to get it to work by

1. In your **Projects**, select the target.
2. Goto **General** tab on top.
3. Under the '**Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content**' section, add the framework (for me it was CoreNFC). Repeat for other targets.
4. Click on **Build Phases** on top and expand '**Link Binary with Libraries**'.
5. Make the troublesome framework optional (from required).

This allowed me to compile for older/newer iPhones without making any code changes. I hope this helps other.

Comment: doesn't work, app crashes and there is no message indicating crash type instead of a breakpoint on some assembly code.

Comment: why is this needed to make optional ?

Answer (score 10):

My environment: Cocos2d 2.0, Box2d, Objective C

In addition to doing the other answers above I finally went to the General tab and made WatchKit Optional.

[image: Target General Linked Frameworks and Libraries Watchkit.framework Optional]

Answer (score 9):

In my case the solution was to remove the compiled framework from the Embedded Binaries, which was a standalone project in the workspace, clean and rebuild it, and finally re-add to Embedded Binaries.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a third-party framework, and using Cocoapods as your dependency manager, try doing a `pod install` to refresh your pods.

This crash was occurring on a third-party library I was using, so glad the above solution worked for me, hope it works for you!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Resolved for me by unselecting "Copy only when installed" on Build Phases->Embed Frameworks

Comment: It would be nice to know the point of this checkbox if the system does not believe that "debug install" is not "install". Regardless, if it causes a crash of the app on the hardware instead of prohibiting the run of the app with a warning, it's a neat another Xcode defect

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I tried building my project with an iPhone that I never used before and I didn't add a new framework. For me, cleaning up worked fine (**Shift+Command+K**). Maybe it's because I use beta 5 of Xcode 7 and an iPhone 6 with iOS 9 Beta, but it worked.

Comment: And maybe a Clean Build Folder too (CMD+Shift+Alt+K)

Answer (score 5):

For any project or Framework project in Xcode that use pods, one easy way to avoid dynamic library (dylb) not to load is to set you pod file to ink in static mode. To do so, just make sure to don't write the following line in your pod file.

```
use_frameworks!
```

Once the line deleted from your file which you saved, simply run form the console:

```
$ pod update
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, my project is written by objective-c and in the library there are Swift files. So I changed **"Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries"** in my project’s **Build Settings** tab to **Yes** and it became totally okay.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to switch the XcodeKit.framework from "Do Not Embed" -> "Embed & Sign"

[image]

Comment: This allows the thing to compile and run, but I have issues about a bad structured module when uploading to App Store.

Answer (score 2):

If have development pod Delete your app from simulator install from pod -> clean - >  run again...

Answer (score 2):

The same thing was when I've created a new **Configuration and Build Scheme.**

So the solution for me was to run

```
pod install
```

for this newly created Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In **Xcode 11**

I was facing the same issue

Changing **"Do Not Embed"** in **General Tab** > **"Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content"** was still resulting the same error.

What did solved for me was adding the **Framework** in **Build Phases Tab** > **Embed Frameworks section**

--Updated---

I observed that in projects built in previous versions of Xcode **Embed Frameworks Section** is not available when running in Xcode 11, Find the below steps to achieve the solution:

1: First need to add the **New Copy Files Phase** under **Build Phases** tab.

[image]

2: Second change the name of the added phase to **Embed Frameworks**
[image]

3: Change the destination to **Frameworks**.

[image]

4: Add the framework for which the error occurred.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the methods available on internet and my own trial and error tricks 100 times. Finally I was able to solve it. – Apeksha Sahu 6 mins ago
Goto iTunes in Mac --> accounts-->Authorize this computer – Apeksha Sahu 5 mins ago
second step.... Goto developer in settings in iPad and iPhone and reindex with identifiers and clear trust computers everything. It worked for me........ ....... After reinstalling Mac OSHigh seria 10.13.15 version from Mac OS seirra beta latest version, to reinstalling Xcode latest version, after updating all certificates. etc etc etc... as many methods as you can think I did. – [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with changing flag `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` (in earlier xcode versions: `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code`) in the Build Settings from NO to YES.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 11**

1. Navigate to settings of your target and select General.
2. Look for "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content"
3. Keep "Do Not Embed" and make sure that all your targets (if you have more than one) have only set it's own framework and not others targets.

Answer (score 1):

Although everyone is saying to embed the framework under the Embedded Binaries but still it is not working, because we are missing one important step here.

Here are the two right steps to add the binaries under Embedded Binaries tab :

1. Remove the framework which is giving the error from the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" under the General tab.
2. Now add the removed framework only under the Embedded Binaries tab and that is all one would need to do.

Run it on the device and keep that smile ;)

Answer (score 1):

For SumUp Users, if you are loading the latest SumUpSDK.xcFramework, then you need to make sure that it's set to "Embed & Sign" from the application's General tab of the Target.

i.e. to reverse the above statement (making it easier to understand):

1. Go to the "Project Navigator" (i.e. the first icon to show all project items etc)
2. Select your project from the top of the tree.
3. On the menu in the middle of the page (slightly to the right), select your application under "Targets"
4. From the top-tab, select "General"
5. Scroll down to "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content"
6. Select your Lib from the list
7. Select "Embed & Sign" from the drop down list next to it.
8. Clean
9. Re-Build and run.

I hope this helps.

H

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to file in xcode -> Workspace settings
2. Click the arrow next to which appears /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3. Select the Derived data and move it to Trash.
4. Quite the xcode and reopen it.
5. Clean the project and run again.

Above steps resolved my issuses.

Answer (score 0):

In my case app crash only on real device and it occurred for standard library's.
I tryied a lot of steps meintioned before, after 1h i **just delete app from real device and install it again.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was issue in

> Run Script

I just removed Run Script and its working

Answer (score 0):

If you also got this in console besides the log in answer:

> Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:

Probably your framework is build for higher Deployment Version than your app. For example app is built for iOS 12, framework is built for iOS 14 and you run on iOS 12 device.

Answer (score -3):

In case anyone is still experiencing this issue, despite following all the steps outlined in the many other answers, you may need to **revoke** and **recreate your code signing certificate**, as per the following:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html

Comment: Exactly. Code signing has nothing to to with this error.

Comment: In this particular case where the signing certificate is not trusted or not in the keychain, the Signature is invalid is the actual error followed by library not found. So I will support this answer. Yet it do not fit to the logs in question but it will help somebody. cheers!