# use dynamic library in xcode 6 have error: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/xxx.dylib Reason: image not found

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib

i have a beginner of cross-platform programming.
my project is a simple 3d project it works on windows well, it is mananged by vistual sutido 2013.and then, i create projects under xcode 6.

there is a Core library in my project, i have compiled it as a dll file under windows, and static link it by a tool which is named Editorbuilder, this tool used to build editor script. the Core project which is Core.vcxproj generate a Core.dll under ProjectRoot/Binaries/Win32/Debug/. EditorBuilder.vcxproj generate a EditorBuilder.exe under ProjectRoot/Binaries/Win32/Debug. if i run this tool in visual studio or the console window, it works well.

under macos, i use xcode 6.
first i have create a dynamic library project, it has a product libCore.dylib, it will generate to ProjectRoot/Binaries/Mac/Debug. and then i create the EditorBuilder project in xcode 6 which is a normal command line tools,and add the reference of libCore.dylib to the product:

[image: the picture of projects]
the picture of projects

[image: the files is generated success]
the files is generated success

it compile success, and works well if i debug EditorBuilder Under Xcode6 use Ctrl + R.
but when i run EditorBuilder in the terminal or double click it, it can not launch up because this :

```
/Users/bodong/Documents/Hikari/Binaries/Mac/Debug/EditorBuilder ; exit;
bodeMacBook-Pro:~ bodong$ /Users/bodong/Documents/Hikari/Binaries/Mac/Debug/EditorBuilder ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/bodong/Documents/Hikari/Binaries/Mac/Debug/EditorBuilder
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout
```

so my question is that the libCore.dylib is in the same directory, why the EditorBuilder process can't find the dylib? 
why the EditorBuilder can find the dylib when run it in xcode 6 with Ctrl + R ?

what's the difference between windows dll and macos dylib?
what is the search strategy under macos?

---

ps:
  if i create a directory /usr/local/lib,and copy libCore.dylib to this dir, it works well.
how to make the EditorBuilder load the dylib which is the same parent dir.????

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer at this post:

[iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)

Reply stays here for reference.

This post in the same page, explains why this happens:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28469804/999817

Answer (score -1):

there is a install directory in the build settings, change this directory to the output directory, it works well.
but i don't know if i deploy this app to another mac, should it works well?