# iOS 8 App Crash on Launch (LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, ios8.1

I ended up with an app crash and got exactly these two lines of log when I do the following steps:
Build and run my iOS 8.1 Swift app on simulator, terminate the app in the simulator by double pressing the home button and swiping up the app, go to the home screen and press the app to start it fresh. Then it crashes.

> Jan 24 21:30:10 MacBook-Air assertiond[22907]: assertion failed: 14C99d 12B411: assertiond + 11523 [3F572A0B-7E12-378D-AFEE-EA491BAF2C36]: 0x1
>
> Jan 24 21:30:10 MacBook-Air.local SpringBoard[22903]: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image

I have tried resetting the simulator, cleaning and rebuilding...but that did not help at all.

EDIT1 - The following is the crash log:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftHTTP.framework/SwiftHTTP
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/980D3F04-A65D-4F01-B3DF-5952FD91BEC3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BB857CAA-8E66-4B98-80B1-D6591F453445/myapp.app/myapp
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x10550e000 -        0x10553261f +dyld_sim (353.2.1) <EE50CD24-1E90-32CE-A2A6-9D5777ED53A6> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim
    0x7fff6fb72000 -     0x7fff6fba8837  dyld (353.2.1) <65DCCB06-339C-3E25-9702-600A28291D0E> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Comment: Neither of those are particularly relevant.  If you want help, provide your crash log.

Comment: Solved it. I had to add the Embedded Libraries.

Source: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta