# My application stuck on the launching image

Tags: objective-c

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/Pods_OCR_APPLICATION.framework/Pods_OCR_APPLICATION
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/44D4C391-27C2-48D1-BE42-C2F879ABDF2F/OCR-APPLICATION.app/OCR-APPLICATION
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Are you trying to open your project from .xcodeproj instead of opening from .xcworkspace?

Comment: can you please tell your xcode version

Answer (score 0):

Set this setting `Runpath Search Paths` to `@executable_path/Frameworks` in the application

go to these for [devforums.apple.com](https://devforums.apple.com/message/991384) 
[iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)