# i included pods in my swift project and its not running on device (ios 9.2)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

i included pods in my swift project and its not running on device
my device is running iOS 9.2

I'm getting this error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/PeerTalk.framework/PeerTalk
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CE466B0F-957F-484A-968F-30E6F117879B/SmartHome.app/SmartHome
Reason: image not found
```

i tried changing Linked Frameworks And Libraries Pods.framework to optional but it didn't worked for me

this happens with every pod i add

Comment: did u look at what image is not found?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta it didnt worked for me :(