# Framework causing crash only on device

Tags: ios, xcode, bolts-framework

This project was running fine all day, then all of a sudden it crashes when I run on device (but works on simulator):

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts   Referenced
> from:
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../MyApp.app/MyApp
>
> Reason: image not found

My project uses Carthage for other frameworks, but for Parse and Bolts I imported everything manually. I just can't seem to fix this; any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/q/24333981/5276890?

Comment: @RoyFalk Yes, I've tried all of that and it still crashes when running on device. I don't understand why this is happening because the project had been working fine all along with these frameworks before

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by deleting Xcode's Derived Data folder. I had previously only tried deleting the derived data for this specific project, but clearly needed to delete the entire derived data. Hope this helps someone, it was incredibly frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The project worked in Simulator but didn't work on a device. The problem was that I had one letter in the name of the framework with lowercase letter instead of uppercase in `copy-frameworks` run script. That worked on Simulator (Mac has case-insensitive filesystem by default) but didn't work on the device (iOS is using case-sensitive filesystem).