# IOS App crashing on Launch after submission to Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, cocoapods, alamofire

I have a Framework developed and one of user of this framework is complaining that they are unable to push their App to Store as it crashes on Launch (on Device) after submission.

The App runs fine during development/debugging session. Does anyone knows what may be wrong and what needs to be done to resolve this?

Thanks.

The Crash logs provided are attached:

[image: Crash Log 1]

[image: Crash Log 2]

The AlamoFire Library is needed in my Framework so the Client was required it to their podfile target tag.

Comment: It looks like that framework wasn't included in their app store build.

Comment: try solutions provided in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta

Comment: it should fail on simulator as well.. i'm surprised how it passed iTunes Validation