# How to embed framework target in subProject in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I got a problem: iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded XCode8.2.1.
And I found this:[iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)
But it seems that it use the debug-build framework resault.  How to fix this?

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: I use shell script to solve it.  copy .framework file to a fix place in after build script and embad it. But some time the debug simple may lost.