# Getting library not found error with TwilioVideoFramework using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio

I have integrated TwilioVideo Framework using cocoapods.
I can successfully compile the code without any errors but after compiling the code, my code is crashing with below error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/TwilioVideo.framework/TwilioVideo
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E766BE03-A6C7-4BF7-A0B3-9FE2D76844DD/XXXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXXX
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried different answers but nothing worked for me.
Does any one experienced this issue with TwilioVideo Framework.

System Specifications I used:

XCode 8.3.3
Deployment Target 8.1

My Pod file looks as below

```
xcodeproj 'ProjectName'
workspace 'ProjectName'

target :"ProjectName" do
platform :ios, '8.1'

  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
  pod 'SocketRocket', '0.5'
  pod 'TwilioSDK', '~>1.2.6'
  pod 'TwilioVideo', '~> 1.3.0'

end
```

Thanks in Advance.....!

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28469804/28376

Comment: Which version of CocoaPods?