# Application crashes if we compile in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9, podfile

Application started crashing on device when we build application from Xcode 9, the application is working fine on the simulator but crashes on the device. Below are the device crash logs

```
Crash logs 
Sep 22 18:57:33 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[324] <Notice>: 
Process:             Checkout [323]
Path:                
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/13FD366C-4D41-4BC9-B958-
151CDC9E62F3/Checkout.app/Checkout
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Sep 22 18:57:33 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[324] <Notice>: 
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: 
@rpath/libclang_rt.ubsan_ios_dynamic.dylib | Referenced from: 
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/13FD366C-4D41-4BC9-B958-
151CDC9E62F3/Checkout.app/Frameworks/Valid.framework/Base | Reason: 
image not found
```

Embed swift library flag is true and application successfully compiled on machine its crashing as soon as we launch app on device.

Comment: Are you embedding the binaries? See similar SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta

Comment: It looks like it's compiling with the Undefined Behavior Sanitizer on, and then can't find that library. Is `libclang_rt.ubsan_ios_dynamic.dylib` something that's even supposed to be embedded? Either way, try turning off the Undefined Behavior Sanitizer (you'll find it under Diagnostics in the scheme editor)