# Xcode 10 "dyld: Symbol not found: __T0BOWV" How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm run project, and it's error "dyld: Symbol not found: __T0BOWV"
How to fix it?
Thank you...!

[image]

Referenced from:

> /Users/letai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5E16F1A-C17C-4C65-B743-73775C820891/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A7E06426-84F9-45DF-8063-337D094BED80/A.app/Frameworks/PKHUD.framework/PKHUD
>
> Expected in:
> /Users/letai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5E16F1A-C17C-4C65-B743-73775C820891/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A7E06426-84F9-45DF-8063-337D094BED80/A.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
>
> in
>
> /Users/letai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5E16F1A-C17C-4C65-B743-73775C820891/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A7E06426-84F9-45DF-8063-337D094BED80/A.app/Frameworks/PKHUD.framework/PKHUD

Comment: Try command + sift + option + k to clean your project files

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work :(

Comment: from xcode file -> WorkSpaceSetting -> build system change it to Legacy build system

Comment: 1. Try making PKHUD.framework in your build phases as Optional.

2. Try setting Build Settings > Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries to YES

Comment: @A.Munzer It not working

Comment: @Arun I tried, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Change the status of newly added framework from "Required" to "Optional" from General Setting of project target.

Answer (score 0):

Find the match Xcode version:

```
otool -L YOUR_FRAMEWORK

#
# ...
@rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1001.0.69)
```

Now you just have to lookup for the Swift version with [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Xcode&section=20#Latest_versions).

```
Xcode   Swift version string 
10.2    5.0 (swiftlang-1001.0.69.5 clang-1001.0.46.3)
```