# Crash with "Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableURLRequest"

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlrequest, cfnetwork

I have installed my app from Xcode 5.1.1 in debug mode on iPad 3 with iOS 7.1.1, as show below in crash log. In day of installing app was working fine. I was not using my iPad for 2 days and today it just crashes on Splash screen, at first second. Restart of iOS does not helped.

Any ideas why it could happening? I will re-add CFNetwork and Foundation frameworks to my project, just in case, but maybe it's something other? Could be it a bug in iOS?

```
Incident Identifier: 24087CE7-3EBE-4FFB-ABC0-091495F774BF
CrashReporter Key:   4d82b50f4190912e3298f7f5ba036ac01d4e6116
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:             EAU4 [131]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/ED697CB6-A7D5-4E54-BE8F-E9B7F3D0D38C/EAU4.app/EAU4
Identifier:          com.develoer.ipad
Version:             4.0 (4.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-06-09 22:38:35.028 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableURLRequest
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/ED697CB6-A7D5-4E54-BE8F-E9B7F3D0D38C/EAU4.app/EAU4
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
 in /var/mobile/Applications/ED697CB6-A7D5-4E54-BE8F-E9B7F3D0D38C/EAU4.app/EAU4
  Dyld Version: 324.1

Binary Images:
0x2be46000 - 0x2be66fff dyld armv7  <651a31c39f71311f965f8ac44de02c88> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2d1b1000 - 0x2d2b3fff AVFoundation armv7  <e6f4e322434733c2a6d074bdc226b08d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x2d2b4000 - 0x2d2dcfff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7  <0bae9ec49a9637c696edf86d86a32db6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x2d2dd000 - 0x2d2ddfff Accelerate armv7  <0424978b39f037a7b3bf9aad5b34a5b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x2d2e7000 - 0x2d4b3fff vImage armv7  <c4834965bdc638fcb1082f53a7721f42> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
...... link on others frameworks .....
```

**Update:**
Found similar question [dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate when trying to run iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043532/dyld-symbol-not-found-nsurlauthenticationmethodclientcertificate-when-trying?rq=1)

Comment: Have you used the debugger to try to track down the line where the crash occurs?

Answer (score 6):

Try re-adding Foundation.framework:

1. Go to your project's target
2. Choose "General" tab
3. Under "Linked Frameworks an Libraries" look for Foundation.framework, select it and press the minus ('-') sign at the buttom to remove this framework.
4. Now press the plus sign ('+') and search for Foundation.framework - re-add it, and it's supposed to fix your crash.

Hope it works - it did for me.

Comment: Thank you! This happened for me in Xcode 6-beta. I was testing an app on my phone, everything working fine, then, all of a sudden the next time I went to run the app on the phone it gave me this error (running on simulator didn't error). In my case, Foundation.framework wasn't even in the Linked Frameworks list. I added it, and it runs on the phone again. Guess it's not just a beta Xcode 6 issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong explaining the situation. Will try again. I did just build in one day and it was ok. On another day I've just launched app by icon and it's crashed. After rebuild everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter :

*Check if there is connectivity package you have used or not. Replaced with **connectivity_plus** plugin and update your **Flutter_ble_plus** plugin* .