# App runs on iPhone 5s but not on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, parse-platform, ios8

I am using Xcode 6 beta with iOS 8 on the iPhone 5s the iphone 4s is standard ios 7.1 phone.

[image]

The app runs great on the iPhone 5s but as soon as a try a iphone 4s or the iPhone 4s simulator.
the app breaks out and throws the following error

> dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
>     Referenced from: /Users/MIkeAspinall 1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/data/Applications/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/WeddingsAndMore.app/WeddingsAndMore
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
>    in /Users/MIkeAspinall 1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/data/Applications/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/WeddingsAndMore.app/WeddingsAndMore
>   (lldb)

I'm not sure why this is happening. But the iPhone 5s simulator throws the same error. It just seems to run on the iOS 8.

the settings are set for an ios 7.1 phone
im also using parse.com for my data access

My Phone is Iphone 5s Running ios 8 beta

iphone 4s is running ios 7.1

simulators are running in xcode 6beta

app is set to run on ios 7.1 or above. 
i'm using xcode 6beta
hope that clears up what i have

opening code on first view controler

```
@interface DMKHomeViewController (UIViewcontroller )
@end

@implementation DMKHomeViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(BOOL) hasInternet{
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.bbc.co.uk"];
NetworkStatus internetStats = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

if (internetStats == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *alertOne = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:@"  A connection To The Internet IS Required While Running This App. Please Reconnect To Continue"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alertOne show];


    }
    else {
       UIAlertView *alerttwo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Connection Active"   message:@"A connection To The Internet IS Required While Running This App. Your Connection Is Live...   Thankyou." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alerttwo show];

}
return YES;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self hasInternet];


    if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
    // Create the log in view controller
    PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

    // Create the sign up view controller
    PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
    [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

    // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
    [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

    // Present the log in view controller
    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }




}



// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the log in request should be submitted to the server.
- (BOOL)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController shouldBeginLogInWithUsername: (NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password {
// Check if both fields are completed
if (username && password && username.length != 0 && password.length != 0) {
    return YES; // Begin login process
}

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                            message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!"
                           delegate:nil
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
return NO; // Interrupt login process
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;   
}


// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the sign up request should be submitted to the server.
- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info {
BOOL informationComplete = YES;

// loop through all of the submitted data
for (id key in info) {
    NSString *field = [info objectForKey:key];
    if (!field || field.length == 0) { // check completion
        informationComplete = NO;
        break;
    }
}

// Display an alert if a field wasn't completed
if (!informationComplete) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                                message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!"
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

return informationComplete;

}


// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is signed up.
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; // Dismiss the PFSignUpViewController
}

// Sent to the delegate when the sign up attempt fails.
    - (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController  didFailToSignUpWithError:   (NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to sign up...");
}

// Sent to the delegate when the sign up screen is dismissed.
- (void)signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController {
NSLog(@"User dismissed the signUpViewController");
}


// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is logged in.
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}



// Sent to the delegate when the log in attempt fails.
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didFailToLogInWithError:  (NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to log in...");
}

    // Sent to the delegate when the log in screen is dismissed.
- (void)logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before    navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
DMKHomeViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];

destination.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyAutomatic;

}






- (IBAction)Logout:(id)sender {
[PFUser logOut];
// Present the log in view controller
if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
    // Create the log in view controller
    PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

    // Create the sign up view controller
    PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
    [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

    // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
    [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

    // Present the log in view controller
    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


}
```

Comment: you have an "iOS 8 phone"? Please clarify in your question iPhone devices vs simulator

Comment: check edit systems explained

Comment: you have zero build issues and nothing reported in the static analyzer?

Comment: 2014-06-10 16:18:13.663 WeddingsAndMore[277:19309] WARNING: Slow defaults access for key ClientStateLogging took 0.035366 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000
2014-06-10 16:18:13.663 WeddingsAndMore[277:19241] WARNING: Slow defaults access for key ClientStateLogging took 0.037351 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000
2014-06-10 16:18:13.836 WeddingsAndMore[277:19241] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
Jun 10 16:18:14 Mikes-iPhone WeddingsAndMore[277] <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. .....from my iphone

Comment: those are runtime log statements. You need to check what build issues result from compilation and run the static analyzer (Product -> Analyze). Do that first and advise if you are still seeing runtime dyld crashes.

Comment: when i do (Product -> Analyze) im seeing nothing coming up. totaly clean. check image attached after alalyze

Comment: have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043532/dyld-symbol-not-found-nsurlauthenticationmethodclientcertificate-when-trying

Comment: yep i have already re added the Foundation framework. and still the same ... i think i will continue to build. and wait for an update for xcode