# Xcode 6 and Cocoapods not referencing iOS frameworks correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, xcode6

After installing Pods in an Xcode 6 project, the iOS frameworks in the Pod Project (e.g. CoreText, CFNetwork etc) all appear red and have the incorrect paths, it runs fine on simulator but when attempting to build onto device this results in a crash:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/3068D977-8690-44B7-A683-    
8E213B7AA615/NoodleLive.app/NoodleLive
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
in /var/mobile/Applications/3068D977-8690-44B7-A683-8E213B7AA615/NoodleLive.app/NoodleLive
(lldb)
```

The incorrect paths point to

```
'/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework'
```

If it was the correct path, instead of 'iPhoneOS7.1.sdk' it should be pointing to 'iPhoneOS8.0.sdk'

I'm using the latest version of cocoapods and have changed command line tools to Xcode 6.0. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The crash wasn't down to incorrect file paths on the Pods iOS frameworks, turns out that doesn't matter. This question solved my problem:

[dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate when trying to run iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043532/dyld-symbol-not-found-nsurlauthenticationmethodclientcertificate-when-trying)

Was down to a bug in iOS8sdk where symbols have been moved between CFNetwork and Foundation and the frameworks needed to be reordered in the pod.xconfig file. CFNetwork needs to go after Foundation.