# dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSDictionary0__ when using google ServiceGenerator binary with discovery docs in XCode 7 & iOS target 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to generate client API code from Google backend using Google `serviceGenerator` with discovery document as input. Following is the exact command :

```
/Users/raja/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-dycdiotwolfqnaelznaucewpppjr/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator ./userRecordApi-v1-rpc.discovery --outputDir ~/API
```

I however, see the following error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSDictionary0__
  Referenced from: /Users/raja/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-dycdiotwolfqnaelznaucewpppjr/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator (which was built for Mac OS X 10.11)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
 in /Users/raja/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-dycdiotwolfqnaelznaucewpppjr/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
Raja.

Answer (score 6):

Making the CoreFoundation framework optional worked for me. If it is not listed in libraries list add it and then make it optional.

Answer (score 5):

My project was building fine on Xcode 6 but failed with this error for one of the components. Obviously this is a framework linking versioning issue and I was able to get my binary to run by setting the OS X Deployment target to 10.9 - the same as the other components in my project. I would review your project component base and deployment SDK settings.

Comment: It's absolutely it. My iOS app had Deployment target 8.0 and one of the dependencies was a static lib set to "Default" target, which Xcode7 helpfully rendered to 9.0. I was confused by the runtime error being reported by the main app binary - which is now totally obvious for a static lib.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  For me I needed to switch the `iOS Deployment Target` to the same value for all of my linked frameworks and test targets.