# dyld: Symbol not found on iOS8/xcode7

Tags: ios

I am using xcode 7 to develop an app. Its target OS is iOS8. When i run the app on devices running iOS9 everything works fine but on iOS8 devices the app crashes and i get this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSArray0__
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxx/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx
```

Comment: please can you check all the frame works are properly added and if  yes than remove and readd  it means foundation framework not sure but i think this will help you also re add core foundation framework

Comment: hope this will help you.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA does not seem to work, i still get this error

Comment: have you check and readd  CoreFoundation framework?

Comment: yes i have added corefoundation to my frameworks, but no luck

Comment: sorry my friend now i have no any other solution for that. Hope you'll get solution for that soooonn.

Comment: I think this will help you can you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043532/dyld-symbol-not-found-nsurlauthenticationmethodclientcertificate-when-trying.

Comment: if this answer helps you than replay me please..

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA thanks for the quick reply, but i still didnt have any luck getting this fixed